# Data structure to check if a static array does not contain an element of a given range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I'm stuck for hours on the following homework question for data-structures class:

> You are given a static set S (i.e., S never changes) of n integers from {1, . . . , u}.
>
> Describe a data structure of size O(n log u) that can answer the following queries in O(1) time:
>
> `Empty(i, j)` - returns TRUE if and only if there is no element in S that is between i and j (where i and j are integers in {1, . . . , u}).

At first I thought of using a y-fast-trie.

Using y-fast-trie we can achieve O(n) space and O(loglogu) query (by finding the successor of i and check if it's bigger than j).

But O(loglogu) is not O(1)...

Then I thought maybe we can sort the array and create a second array of size n+1 of the ranges that are not in the array and then in the query we would check if [i, j] is a sub-range of one of the ranges but I didn't thought of any way to do it that uses O(nlogu) space and can answer the query in O(1).

I have no idea how to solve this and I feel like I'm not even close to the solution, any help would be nice.

Comment: "n integers from {1, . . . , u}" I don't understand this, does it mean n integers in the range [1, u]? Without repetitions, I suppose (a set, not a multiset), so n < u?

Comment: @jdehesa it means array of n integers in the range [1,u]. And it doesn't really matter if repititions are allowed or not because we can remove duplicates before answering the queries.

Comment: Are you including `i` and `j` when you say `returns TRUE if and only if there is no element in S that is between i and j`?

Comment: It seems you need to expand on your computational model. Which operations are considered `O(1)`? For example, is `i - j` a constant time, or `log u` time?

Comment: @user58697 having `i - j` anything other than `O(1)` makes it only harder, so lets assume it's `O(1)` ;)

Comment: I'll be surprised if you can meet the requirements as stated.  The best results for succinct compressed bit vectors could do your queries in constant time, but they only meet the space requirement if S is not too small compared to u.  They support rank queries that are stronger than yours, though, so maybe it's possible...  Google "succinct data structures" for info...  but this really seems too hard for homework.

Comment: @user58697 calculating `i-j` is O(1) and when I say O(nlogu) space I mean O(nlogu) registers which actually means O(n(logu)^2) bits

Comment: I've been thinking about this one and I suspect that there's a connection to the predecessor lower bound that would make this one tricky. You can't, in time O(1) and the space bounds provided, answer the question "what's the last item before the range?" or "what's the first item after the range?" So any solution is going to have to solve this problem without actually knowing what elements, if any, fall into the range.

Comment: Since just writing down the set S requires O(n log u) bits, this definitely seems a hard problem. Some exotic kind of hashing seems the only hope.

Comment: @Gene no, data structure of size O(nlogu) means O(nlogu) registers. So it's O(n(logu)^2)) bits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can create a x-fast-trie of S (takes O(nlogu) space) and save in each node the maximum and minimum value of a leaf in it's sub tree. Now we can use that to answer the Empty query in O(1). Like this:

Empty(i, j)
We first calculate xor(i,j) now the number of leading zeros in that number will be the number of leading bits i and j share in common let's mark this number as k. Now we'll take the first k bits of i (or j because they're equal) and check in the x-fast-trie hash table if there's a node that equels to those bits. If there isn't we'll return TRUE because any number between i and j would also have the same k leading bits and since there isn't any number with those leading bits there isn't any number between i and j. If there is let's mark that node as X.

if X->right->minimum > j and X->left->maximum < i we return TRUE and otherwise we return FALSE, because if this is false then there is a number between i and j and if it's true then all the numbers that are smaller than j are also smaller than i and all the numbers that are bigger than i are also bigger than j.

Sorry for bad English

Comment: Wouldn't `XOR(i,j)` also be (at least) `O(log u)`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog No. If in your computational model it takes logu then everything takes logu, it is impossible to do O(1) operations because every operation includes logu bits. Also you can do xor O(1) because you can do it in a nonblocking way.

Comment: There’s also an O(1)-time algorithm independent of word size that computes the longest common prefix of two integers, which would be useful here.

Comment: Does following refute it, or I'm wrong? Let's say `u`==16, `S`=={1,2,14,15}. And `i`==6 (binary `b0110`), `j`==9 (`b1001`). Then `xor(i,j)`==`b1111`. `k`==0. `X` - root of the x-fast-trie. `X->right->minimum`==14 > `j`==9 and `X->left->maximum`==2 < `i`==6 , so returning FALSE (which is not correct as there is no element between `i`==6 and `j`==9)

Comment: @Renat right, I meant the opposite with the true and false, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You haven't clarify either the numbers given will be sorted or not. If not, sort them, while will take O(nlogn).
2. Find upper bound of i, say x. Find lower bound of j, say y.
3. Now just check 4 numbers. Numbers at index x, x+1, y-1 and y. If any of the numbers of the given array is between i and j return true. Otherwise return false.

If the given Set/Array is not sorted, then in this approach additional O(nlogn) is required to sort it. Memory requires O(n). For each query, it's O(1).

Comment: How do you propose to find the upper and lower bounds in time O(1)? I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: Oh sorry, Upper bound and lower bound consumes log(n).

Answer (score 0):

Consider a data structure consisting of

- an array `A[1,...,u]` of size `u` such that `A[i]=1` if `i` is present in S, and `A[i]=0` otherwise. This array can be constructed from set `S` in O(n).
- an array `B[1,...,u]` of size `u` which stores cumulative sum of `A` i.e. `B[i] = A[1]+...+A[i]`. This array can be constructed in O(u) from `A` using the relation `B[i] = B[i-1] + A[i]` for all `i>1`.
- a function `empty(i,j)` which returns the desired Boolean query. If `i==1`, then define `count = B[j]`, otherwise take `count = B[j]-B[i-1]`. Note that `count` gives the number of distinct elements in S lying in range `[i,j]`. Once we have `count`, simply return `count==0`. Clearly, each query takes O(1).

Edit: As pointed out in comments, the size of this data structure is O(u), which doesn't matches the constraints. But I hope it gives others an approximate target to shoot at.

Comment: Its a working solution but doesn't fit the constraints: The size is O(u), not O(n). And O(u) can be greater than O(n log u)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a solution, but impossible to write it in a comment. There is an idea of how to solve the more specific task that possibly will help to solve the generic task from the question.

The specific task is the same except the following point, u = 1024. Also, it isn't a final solution, it is a rough sketch (for the specific task).

Data structure creation:

1. Create a bitmask for U = { 1, ..., u } - M = 0000.....100001, where Mᵥ = 1 when Uᵥ ∊ S, otherwice = 0.
2. Save bitmask M as 'unsigned intgers 32' array = G (32 items). Each item of G contains 32 items from M.
3. Combine integer H = bitmask where Hᵣ = 0 when Gᵣ = 0, otherwice = 1
4. Convert G to **G** that is HashMap r to Gᵣ. **G** is  G but contains records for Gᵣ != 0 only.

Images in the following pseudocode use 8 bits except 32, just for simplicity.

```
Empty(i, j) {
   I = i / 32
   J = j / 32

   if I != J {
```

[image]

```
       if P == 0: return true
```

[image]

```
       if P(I) == 0: return true
```

[image]

```
       if P(J) == 0: return true

   } else {
```

[image: 9999]

```
       if P(J=I) == 0: return true
   }

   return false
}
```

Comment: The current solution has a tree with deep = 2.  Max data size = min(sqrt(u), n) + 1. Expected O has multiplier n. Maybe tree with other deep will be a solution for the generic task. It needs some playing with extremums. This scetch is some example to think. So sorry if it leads dead end. If I will have time - I will contribute more efforts to the current task.

Comment: Interesting idea! But doesn’t this use O(u) space, exceeding the space limitation?

Comment: @templatetypedef, yes but O(u) bits, O(sqrt(u)) integers. And O (sqrt(u)) is O of the worst-case, this case guarantees that n >= sqrt(u). Expected O is O (n * ...). I think this way of the solution has perspectives.

Comment: Can you explain how you got from O(u) bits to O(sqrt u) total integers? Also, how did you get that n >= sqrt(u)?

Comment: In my sample u=1024. "2. Save bitmask as 'unsigned integers 32' array = G (32 items)" We save 32 bits in each of 32 integers. "4. Convert G to  that is HashMap r to Gᵣ. r in Gᵣ is an index of the integer (of 32 bits), not of the bit (as in M). 
4. Convert G to  that is G but contains records for Gᵣ != 0." We don't save integers Gᵣ = 0 in . Our bitmask M contains 1(set bit) for each element of S, that means to has  with max size = 32 integers ("worst-case") it is necessary to have n >= 32 n >=(sqrt(u)) to has minimum one 1(set bit) in each item of .

Comment: I had edited my post. Especially: now U and M are subscribing with v. H, G,  are still subscribing with r.

Comment: @templatetypedef O(u) bits is O(u/log(u)) integers.